# Ramda: find object key by nested key value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Is there any function in ramda how can I find key by nested key value? I found a way how to find an object in array but that doesn't help. I need something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '1'
  },
  addUser: {
    mutationId: '2'
  },
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '3'
  }
}
const findByMutationId = R.???
findByMutationId('2', obj) // returns addUser
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` combined with `propEq` and `keys` should work

```js
const obj = {
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '1'
  },
  addUser: {
    mutationId: '2'
  },
  addCompany2: {
    mutationId: '3'
  }
}
const findByMutationId = id => obj => R.find(
  R.o(R.propEq('mutationId', id), R.flip(R.prop)(obj)),
  R.keys(obj)
)

console.log(findByMutationId('2')(obj))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Pointfree versions **for the lulz**

```js
const obj = {
  addUser: {
    mutationId: '2'
  },
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '3'
  }
}

const findByMutationId = R.compose(
  R.o(R.head),
  R.o(R.__, R.toPairs),
  R.find,
  R.o(R.__, R.nth(1)),
  R.propEq('mutationId')
)

console.log(findByMutationId('2')(obj))

const findByMutationId2 = R.compose(
  R.ap(R.__, R.keys),
  R.o(R.find),
  R.o(R.__, R.flip(R.prop)),
  R.o,
  R.propEq('mutationId')
)

console.log(findByMutationId2('3')(obj))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about ramda, but if a one-liner in plain js is good for you, the following will work

```js
const obj = {
    addCompany: {
        mutationId: '1'
    },
    addUser: {
        mutationId: '2'
    }
};

let found = Object.keys(obj).find(e => obj[e].mutationId === '2');
console.log(found);
```

Comment: `Object.values` would simplify this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are gona use this then you might have to polyfill entries, this is good if you need both the key and the value

```js
const obj = {
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '1'
  },
  addUser: {
    mutationId: '2'
  },
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '3'
  }
}

let [key, val] = Object.entries(obj).find(obj => obj[1].mutationId == '2')

console.log(key)
console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but better late than never. You could also wrap some of the functions in `curry()` if you want to make them more composable in the future.

```js
const obj = {
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '1'
  },
  addUser: {
    mutationId: '2'
  },
  addCompany: {
    mutationId: '3'
  }
}

// search key in obj, where a value satisfies pred
const findObjKey = pred =>
  pipe(
    toPairs,
    find(compose(pred, nth(1))),
    nth(0)
  )

const findByMutationId = (id, obj) => findObjKey(propEq('mutationId', id))(obj)

const res = findByMutationId('2', obj)
console.log(res)
```